# Get properties from response of Sequelize using TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Given this model:

```
const User = sql.define("user", {
    firstName: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastName: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    }
});
```

And this query:

```
User.findOne().then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(user.firstName); // ERROR
});
```

How can I get the `firstName` property from the sql response?

I have tried:

- `user.firstName` but it says: Property does not exist on type {}

Comment: `JSON.stringify` returns a `string`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes I've noticed, so that approach wouldn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `JSON.stringify` goes from JavaScript value to JSON formatted string (serializes). `JSON.parse` goes from JSON formatted string to JavaScript value (deserializes). Isn't the point of that library to automatically deserialize in which case you don't have to do anything?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I just want to be able to `console.log(user.firstName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you can simply:

```
User.findOne().then(function(user) {
    console.log(user.getDataValue("firstName"));
});
```

Or if you have a `User` model you can cast the response to be of type `User`:

```
User.findOne().then(function(response) {
    const user = response as User;
    console.log(user.firstName));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because the compiler can't determine a type for the `user` variable.

You have to options. Either declare and use a type for it. Or just declare user as having the `any` type.

You can try having a look at [squelize typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript) for a better integration of sequelize with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Its Feb 2023 and if you have just started working with Sequelize with typescript, the way I'm making it work and not changing a bunch of this is to use the method get() inherited from the Model base class

```
var user:UserModel = UserModel.create({"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Griffin"}).get()
console.log(user.firstname) // Peter
```

The idea is that get() returns an object with all properties of that specific model so that you can access what you want, and also show them on autocomplete
Similarly you can use getDataValue("firstName") to get just one of the properties

I wish there would be a way to set sequelize config to make get() be automatic somehow but I could not find such thing